# How to log an error when Azure App Configuration reload fails

Tags: c#, azure, logging, configuration, azure-app-configuration

I'm using Azure App Configuration with the dynamic configuration using poll model enabled, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/enable-dynamic-configuration-aspnet-core?tabs=core6x). My goal is to log an error message when the configuration reload fails for any reason, like an incorrect key-vault reference. Here's the method which adds Azure App Configuration as the configuration source.

```
public static IConfigurationBuilder AddAppConfiguration(IConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder, IEnumerable<string> filters)
    {
        if (!configurationBuilder.Sources.Any())
        {
            configurationBuilder.AddDefaultConfigurationSources();
        }
        
        var configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
        var appConfiguration = configuration.GetSection(AppConfiguration.ConfigurationKey)
            .Get<AppConfiguration>();
        
        if (appConfiguration?.IsEnabled == true)
        {
            if (appConfiguration.IsRedundancyEnabled)
                configurationBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(
                    options =>
                    {
                        ConfigureAppConfiguration(options, appConfiguration, appConfiguration.UrlSecondary, filters, appConfiguration.Label);
                    }, true);

            configurationBuilder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(
                options => { ConfigureAppConfiguration(options, appConfiguration, appConfiguration.Url, filters, appConfiguration.Label); },
                true);
        }

        return configurationBuilder;
    }
```

Please note that the `optional` parameter in `AddAzureAppConfiguration` is set to `true`. This means that the application won't crash if the configuration refresh fails and will just keep running with the old settings, I'd like to keep that behavior.

I've tried to use the *ChangeToken* to log an error if the configuration hasn't changed like this:

```
configuration.GetReloadToken().RegisterChangeCallback(state =>
{
    var reloadToken = state as IChangeToken;
    if (reloadToken.HasChanged)
    {
        logger.Information("Configuration refresh successful");
    }
    else
    {
        logger.Error("Configuration refresh failed");
    }
            
    RegisterCallback(logger, configuration);
}, configuration.GetReloadToken());
```

But the callback only actually gets called if the configuration did in fact change , at least I didn't manage to get it to fail and log the error.

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://github.com/Azure/AppConfiguration-DotnetProvider/pull/273#issue-972987151), the default ILoggerFactory will be added automatically when `services.AddAzureAppConfiguration()` is invoked in your `ConfigureServices()` method through DI. I was not seeing logs because the Microsoft minimum log level was set to *Error*, while the AzureAppConfigurationProvider logs *Warning* if the `TryRefreshAsync()` method fails.

Comment: Failures that occurred during the config refresh are not fatal. The App Configuration provider library will simply refresh next time. The application will continue functioning with the cached config. This is why any failures during the config refresh are logged as warnings.